# Is there possibility into SQL server to get size (in bytes) for group of records

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I know in SQL Server there is possibility to get size of whole table in bytes.

And having total size I can calculate approximate size of one record and then multiply it to amount for different groups  of records - but this will be approximate size.

Is there way to get exact size for group of records produced by a `GROUP BY` statement ?

Thank you,

Comment: Table or table with indices? What about compression?

Comment: Yes there are indexes and compression is being used. Is there way I can calculate size of the indexes as well ?

Comment: Do you want to calculate the index size on a per column basis?  Also, do you want the actual size on disk or the nominal size in the database?

Comment: I think calculation index size and nominal size will be good enough.

Answer (score 1):

This pattern appears to work, but I'm not 100% confident in the results as it's not an area I know much about.

```
Select a,b,c, SUM(DATALENGTH(a), SUM(DATALENGTH(b)), SUM(DATALENGTH(c)) from
table group by a,b,c
```

Comment: Is there way to calculate size of indexes for the table ?